# Removing sprites from screen

Tags: c#, xna, sprite

How can we remove sprites from certain co-ordinates position on the screen on occurance of certain event in C#-XNA?

Comment: Thats a very broad question that depends on how you are rendering them, how you are tracking those sprites, etc. The main answer is to simply stop rendering the affected sprites. Show some code and write a more specific question if you want a more specific answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you don't erase anything from the screen. Instead, for every frame, you render everything into a buffer and then render the finished buffer to the screen (to avoid flickering). When the next frame comes, it simply overwrites the previous content on the screen.

So, as said in the comment, you don't erase a sprite - you just don't render it in the next frame. How you achieve that depends on how you manage your `Draw` cycle.